# How to add image tag inside title attribute of an anchor tag?

Tags: html, image

I have added an img tag inside title attribute,but the img tag shows as text when hover over link(using hovertip js),and does not display an image.What needs to be done?

```
<a title="4r23r 2342.00 &lt;img src=/m/productsmedia/IHALE.GIF&gt;" class="product_detail " href="/?product=6" id="0">4r23r</a>
```

Comment: *Inhale deeply* You did **what**!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You cannot!** You need to use custom tooltip look-a-like effect with IMG insdie DIV and on mouseHover event.

Here is [an example](http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/03/).

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in HTML, at least not what you appear to be attempting.

If you want a clickable image, you put the `img` tag inside the `a` tag, not inside an attribute:

```
<a title="4r23r 2342.00" class="product_detail " href="/?product=6" id="0">
 <img src="/m/productsmedia/IHALE.GIF" />
</a>
```

If you want a tooltip that contains an image, you need to code it using javascript and css. There are plenty of [articles](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/A_Simple_Tooltip.aspx) describing how to achieve this.