# Image Tooltip to work after Datatable Next Page

Tags: jquery, tooltip

[Datatables Tooltip Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913080/datatables-tooltip-image/16914214#16914214)

I asked this question yesterday and thought I got the solution. However I  have just realised that the the images do not pop-up in a tooltop if I click on next page. They only work on the default page that is returned...ie first 10 rows. If I go to the next page of results or expand the table to show more than 10 rows the hover tooltip does not work.

is there anyway to reinitalised the hover?

please not I tried adding these to the document ready function:

```
$('.next').click(function () {
     screenshotpreview();
 });

$('.pagination').click(function() {
 screenshotpreview();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.next', function () {
    screenshotpreview();
});

$(document).on('click', '.pagination', function() {
    screenshotpreview();
});
```

Event delegation is the issue. Bind to a static parent element, so that dynamically added elements can still fire.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ohgodwhy. I tried this but still didn't work. I will continue using this framework though.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are setting the tooltip on the document.ready function. Try initializing your tooltip outside of the document.ready function

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this code in your datatables. it's like a listener for Datatables. Everytime any changes in Datatables occurs it will execute the functions in it

```
"drawCallback": function( settings ) {   
    toolTipShow(); // your tootlip function.
},
```

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ it's like a listener for Datatables. Everytime any changes in Datatables occurs it will execute the functions in it.

Comment: you should include that into your answer as your answer looks like a code dump.