# How to bring up a div box while hovering over a span tag in a section?

Tags: html, css, hover

I tried to figure out how to hover over a span tag and then bring up a div box that was customized? Right now, I have the span tag attributed to title that will automatically hover and explain what it is, but I don't want a default one the browser uses but instead, I want to be able to use my own div "define_box" that I constructed to display when hovered over the span tag. How do I do this?

MY FULL CODE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/Mu2TS/

The focus of my **CSS** code is here:

```
#message > span:hover{

}
.define_box{ /*a definition box appears when hovered*/
height:100px;
width:500px;
background-color:#000;
color:#FFFE41;
font-weight:bold;
border: 1px solid #FFFE41;
/*z-index:-14;*/
display:none; /*hide the element until hovered*/
}
```

**HTML:**

Camera Phone

```
            <p id="message">The first camera phone known as the J-Phone was sold in 2000 in Japan. The first generations of camera phones used 
            <span style="cursor:help;text-decoration:underline;" title="Charge Coupled Device is a light-sensitive integrated circuit that stores and displays the data for an image in such a way that each pixel (picture element) in the image is converted into an electrical charge the intensity of which is related to a color in the color spectrum. (techtarget)">Charge Coupled Device (CCD)</span>. Today, about 90% of 
            camera phones use <span style="cursor:help;text-decoration:underline;" title="Complementary metal-oxide-semiconductor is the semiconductor technology used in transistors. In a complementary way, it forms an effective means of electrical control. CMOS transistors uses less power when not needed. However, it does become hot when rapid direction changes are being used such as taking a snapshot. (techtarget)">Complementarymetal-oxide-semiconductor (CMOS)</span> 
            image sensor technology that improves somewhat over CCD by using way less power enhancing battery life, 
            less expensive to produce, but slightly lower in quality and resolution than CCDs. In 1997, Philippe Kahn pictures of his daughter&rsquo;s birth were
            the first known publicly shared pictures via a cell phone device to his families and friends. In 2003, more camera phones were being sold 
            worldwide than digital cameras. By 2006, more than half of mobile phones had a built-in camera. In 2010, the number of camera phones worldwide
            totaled to more than a billion. In 2012, Nokia announced the Nokia 808 PureView featuring 41-megapixel 1/1.2-inch sensor running Nokia&rsquo;s 
            Symbian OS. In 2013, the Nokia Lumia 1020, an improved version of the 41-megapixel sensor sports a 2/2-inch sensor, running Windows Phone 8, 
            achieved higher definition and light sensitivity.</p>

            <div class="define_box">
                Charge Coupled Device is a light-sensitive integrated circuit that stores and displays the data for an image in such a way that each pixel (picture element) in the image is converted into an electrical charge the intensity of which is related to a color in the color spectrum. (techtarget)
            </div>

            <div class="define_box">
                Complementary metal-oxide-semiconductor is the semiconductor technology used in transistors. In a complementary way, it forms an effective means of electrical control. CMOS transistors uses less power when not needed. However, it does become hot when rapid direction changes are being used such as taking a snapshot. (techtarget)
            </div>

            <!--<p id="message2"></p>-->
        </section>
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18856072/961695

Comment: For what you are trying to achieve, it'll be pushing it just to use CSS3. Not impossible, but your structuring will turn out to be very messy. Try to use jQuery.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Yes, that's exactly what I want. I tried this, #message > span:hover + div, but the div is not in the p tag. So, how do I back out of the p tag and select the div?

Comment: For this approach to work you will have to place the DIVs right after SPANs. If this approach doesn't work for you - you will have to use JS and onmouseover event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you restructured your HTML so the definition `div`s were immediately after the target `span`s, you could use the CSS next-sibling selector, `+`, to show the `div` when the `span` was hovered.

New HTML:

```
Bla Bla Bla <span class="hard-word">Charge Coupled Device (CCD)</span><div class="definition">They are Bla Bla Bla</div> Bla Bla Bla<span class="hard-word">Another Term</span><div class="definition">They are Blip Blip Blip</div>
```

New CSS:

```
.definition{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    /* other styles */
}
.hard-word:hover + .definition{
    display: block;
}
```