# PHP string formatting issue

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm using a tool tip jquery plugin and it requires single quotes in the link attributes like so:

```
   <a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='my-image.png' width='100' height='100' />
```

however i'm trying to save this inside a php variable like so:

```
$calendar.= '<div class="event-day tooltip"><a href="event.php?id='.$event['event_id'].'"title="<img src="my-image.jpg" width="500" height="400"/><span class="hb">'.$hour.'</span> '.$event['name'].'</a></div>';
```

as you can see in the title attribute it isnt going to work because of title="

Comment: you can also put single quotes in html parkup, I don't think it matters.

Comment: `\'` [see this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: That's not a valid element, as you never close the `a` tag, and also having HTML inside an attribute is not a great idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626627/how-to-add-image-tag-inside-title-attribute-of-an-anchor-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you need to generate this:

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='my-image.png' width='100' height='100' />
```

... but this is completely invalid HTML to begin with.

I suspect you actually want to insert some arbitrary HTML such as:

```
 <img src='my-image.png' width='100' height='100' />
```

... inside a title attribute:

```
 <a href="#" class="tooltip" title="">Foo</a>
```

It's not particularly difficult:

```
<?php
$title = "<img src='my-image.png' width='100' height='100' />";
echo '<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="' . htmlspecialchars($title) . '">Foo</a>';
```

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="&lt;img src='my-image.png' width='100' height='100' /&gt;">Foo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use escape characters `\'`

```
$calendar.= '<div class="event-day tooltip"><a href="event.php?id='.$event['event_id'].'"title="<img src=\'my-image.jpg\' width=\'500\' height=\'400\'/><span class="hb">'.$hour.'</span> '.$event['name'].'</a></div>';
```

Comment: this is what I have but it doesnt seem to work:

$calendar.= '<div class="event-day"><a href="event.php?id='.$event['event_id'].'"class="tooltip" title="<img src=\''.$event['event_id'].'.jpg\' width=\'500\' height=\'400\'/><span class="hb">'.$hour.'</span> '.$event['name'].'</a></div>';

Answer (score 0):

use \

```
   $calendar.= '<div class="event-day tooltip"><a href="event.php?id='.$event['event_id'].'"title="<img src=\'my-image.jpg\' width=\'500\' height=\'400\'" /><span class="hb">'.$hour.'</span> '.$event['name'].'</a></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to add space before `title="`

```
<a href="event.php?id='.$event['event_id'].'" title="<img src="my-image.jpg" width="500" height="400"/><span class="hb">'.$hour.'</span> '.$event['name'].'</a>';
                                           ^^^^^^
```

Problem is 2 attributes `href` and `title` are mixed in your code. you need to separate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving it in a variable escaping quotes instead of using double quotes in your title attribute.

Also your markup is incorrect since you're closing an `<a>` and a `<div>` that are never opened. (changed it in example below)

```
$calendar.= '<div class="event-day tooltip"><a href="event.php?id='.$event['event_id'].'"title="<img src=\'my-image.jpg\' width=\'500\' height=\'400\'/><span class=\'hb\'>'.$hour.'</span> '.$event['name'].'">';
```

Comment: this is what i have but it doesnt seem to work:

$calendar.= '<div class="event-day"><a href="event.php?id='.$event['event_id'].'"class="tooltip" title="<img src=\''.$event['event_id'].'.jpg\' width=\'500\' height=\'400\'/><span class="hb">'.$hour.'</span> '.$event['name'].'</a></div>';

Comment: Try changing it like this (since your <a> tag syntax will otherwise be incorrect: $calendar.= '<div class="event-day"><a href="event.php?id='.$event['event_id'].'"class="tooltip" title="<img src=\''.$event['event_id'].'.jpg\' width=\'500\' height=\'400\'/>"><span class="hb">'.$hour.'</span> '.$event['name'].'</a></div>';

Answer (score 0):

Store the image tag in a variable and use it as follows:

```
$myImg="<img src='my-image.jpg' width='500' height='400'/>";
$calendar.= "<div class='event-day tooltip'><a href='event.php?id=$event[event_id]' title='$myImg'><span class='hb'>$hour</span>$event[name]</a></div>";
```

Plus, you don't need to concatenate PHP variables when using with strings.

```
echo "Hi $myname, how u doing?";
```

is better than

```
echo "Hi ".$myname.", how u doing?";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$calendar = '<div class="event-day tooltip"><a href="event.php?id='.$event['event_id'].' "title="<img src=\'my-image.jpg\' width="500" height="400"/><span class="hb">'.$hour.'</span> '.$event['name'].'</a></div>';
```